# Theoretical solution to ham radio repeater range extension for personal use

Tags: repeater, range, 2m

So here's the theory,

I build a personal repeater to access a nearby repeater. In turn it sends a signal to my desired repeater (within range of my repeater)
I then build a second repeater to receive on repeater number two's output frequency and send it back to my radio using a ctcss tone.

In theory this should work, right?

Or, would I need my return repeater to send it back on the original repeaters output frequency?

### Simplified

We'll label them as follows:

- R1 the repeater my repeater sends to.
- R2 the repeater I duplex to.
- M1 my transmit repeater.
- M2 my receive repeater.
- TX my radio

My theory is as follows:

- TX to M1 on R1 receive frequency to R2 receive
- From R2 output to M2 to TX with ctcss (no ctcss coming from R2)

Or should it be:

- TX to M1 on R1 receive frequency to R2 receive
- From R2 output to M2 on TX on R1 output frequency

Comment: bit confused. Wouldn't R1 and R2 be the same physical device?

Comment: What you're trying to do is sold as the cross-band repeat function on high-end mobile radios. In commercial radio, the same function goes by many names including _vehicular repeater system_, _extender_, _terminal repeater_, _mobile/vehicular repeater_.

Answer (score 2):

Below are 2 options that you might pursue for your example.

For both options, f1 represents the distant repeater output freq and f2 represents the distant repeater input freq. The crude baseless triangle on the right is intended to represent the distant repeater.

[image: 2 options for an intermediate repeater]

In the top option, the radio can "hear" the far repeater but doesn't have capability to successfully transmit into the repeater. In this case, only an "intermediate  transmit" (from the perspective of your radio) repeater is needed. Note that none of the 3 frequencies should be the same to avoid interference with other stations having different characteristics.

In the second option, the radio doesn't rely upon hearing nor successfully transmitting into the distant repeater on its own. This requires a distinct repeater and frequency pair each for 1) hearing the distant repeater and 2) transmitting into the distant repeater. It's important that neither of f3 or f4 are the same frequency as f1 or f2 to avoid potential transmit loops or interference with other stations that are trying to access the distant repeater.

It seems unlikely to encounter a situation where the radio can successfully transmit into the repeater but not successfully hear it, so I've left that off.

Incidentally, I've actually setup the top option in the past: turn on x-band repeat on my base station and use it as my local intermediate tx repeater whilst wandering about the house with my HT on low power while doing chores etc. HT has distant repeater output on the sub-band (2M freq) and active simplex at 0.1 W EIRP on a 70cM freq which is x-band repeated into the 2M distant repeater input. Just have to remember to pause for an instant on transmit to make sure I'm not cutting myself off.

Comment: Option 2 is hitting on what I'm thinking.

Comment: For example I'm nearly out of range of the repeater that I want to hit (because it's the repeater I frequently use.) I am in range or a secondary repeater that's run by the same trustee. And I plan to travel a bit further. So I want to use the nearer repeater to carry me to my usual repeater to access the operators who usually use the desired repeater. (These are club owned repeaters that, at least temporarily, aren't linked.)

Comment: Assuming the trustee sets up that secondary repeater as the intermediate Rx repeater, you'll still need a solution for the intermediate Tx repeater.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [webmarc's answer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/22490/25441) I'd like to point out that a remote station where your personal repeaters sit would possibly be a more economical solution: instead of two additional receive chains, including filtering and antennas, and two additional transmit chains including antennas and power amplifier, that make up your relay, you could just have one transmitter and one receiver.

If you happen to have access to cellular networks, Internet-based remote operation would become viable. I'm taking a guess here, but by your name and the time of posting, you might be in the UK. If that's the case, you sadly can't use the cheap French or Southeast European cellular data contracts equally in the UK anymore (brexit being the usual downer), but I believe virtual mobile network operators like Talkmobile will only slightly skim the profits of lower competition, so that for the price difference you might have years of sufficient cellular data volume available at your remote station.

Comment: excellent observation